# Issue displaying array in Codeigniter - Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I am trying to implement AJAX call method into my website using codeigniter, so when the user clicks on a button it will update them live.

The click button works and displays all of the JSON data but the issue is when i try and display a specific array it does not print it out it shows single values for example "h"

I want to be able to print specific arrays for example the array that contains the string "Jamie"

Any help would be appreciated

Controller

```
public function insertJSON()
    {
        $this->load->model("values");
        $queryresults = $this->values->getDb();

        $arr = array();
        $arr2 = array();


        foreach($queryresults as $row)
        {
            $arr[] =  $row->post;
            $arr2[] = $row->img;
        }

                    $data = array();
                    $data[] = $arr;
                    $data[] = $arr2;

                    echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

View

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
  $('#getdata').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/welcome/insertJSON';?>',
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result_table').html(data[1]);
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Vardump of the variable

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Jamie"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Mark"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "James"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "hello"
}
[1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "oliver@hotmail.com"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "jakie@hotmail.com"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "mark@hotmail.com"
    [3]=>
    string(16) "james@hotmail.com"
}
}
```

Comment: You have to loop thorough the JSON object

Comment: `data[1]` maps to the second array you had added to the `$data` array. You would need to do `data[0][0]` to get `jamie` and `data[1][0]` to get `oliver@hotmail.com`

Comment: i thought i would have to try 'data[0][0]' to get jamie but instead it displays "<", its really confusing me - i think this suggests that im not grabbing the JSON properly

Answer (score 1):

if you want `display a specific array` then use `[]` operator

```
$('#result_table').html(data[0][0]); //will print Jamie
$('#result_table').html(data[0][3]); //will print hello
$('#result_table').html(data[1][1]); //will print jakie@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this on your returned data:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

So:

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#result_table').html(data[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Info: To get jSON correctly you should set output **TYPE** before putting output like this:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
```

Then set output like this:

```
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

However According to your var dump $data[1] will show **Object[]** and all the above answer is correct. :)